# Accessing static class variables via instantiated objects

Tags: c#

So I came upon some legacy C# code that has a class with some static variables in it.

```
public class TMP_PARAM
{
    // stores params and signals of test
    public static List<filter> data_p;
    public static List<filter> data_p_save;
    public static List<filter> data_s;
    public static List<filter> data_s_save;
    public List<filter> data_operation_p
    {
        get
        {
            return data_p;
        }
        set
        {
            data_p = value;
        }
    }
```

However I was confused when they had data in them even though there was no point in the code where they were set ie:

```
Automobile.Drive();
int i = Automobile.NumberOfWheels;
```

I found out that the variables were being set by different objects via set calls

```
TMP_PARAM tmp = new TMP_PARAM();
tmp.data_operation_p = cast_list;
```

My question is why does the C# compiler allow this? Shouldn't static class variables only be accessed via a class interface?

Comment: `data_operation_p` is not static - so you can access it with a instance and it can access the static variables.  Which part of that should not be allowed?  Granted it's not a good design but it's not _illegal_.

Comment: So long as the class _itself_ is not static, then the class can have a mixture of static and non-static methods.  You'll notice that data_operation_p does not have the static keyword in it; thus, it is an instance method, rather than a static one.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) with `static`. The code marks them as `public`, so they are accessible from the outside. Mark them as `private` and the initialization will then have to be inside the `class` definition.